# Duplicate File1, Split File2 by vendor, Paste splitted data to duplicate file1

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, split

#### Problem Statement:

I need to split an Excel file (`File2`) based on unique values in the 'Vendor Name' column and save each subset as a separate file in an existing Excel workbook (`File1`). However, my current implementation is inefficient and takes a lot of time.

File1 path is blank_order_book_path

File2 dataframe is df

#### Main Part of Code:

```py
suppliers = df['Vendor Name'].unique()
for supplier in suppliers:
    if isinstance(supplier, str):
        safe_supplier = supplier.replace('/', '_')
        supplier_df = df[df['Vendor Name'] == supplier].copy()
        wb = load_workbook(blank_order_book_path)
        ws = wb["Data Dump"]
        data = supplier_df.columns.tolist() + supplier_df.values.tolist()
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(data, 1):
            for col_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
                ws.cell(row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=value)
                wb.save(f"{safe_supplier}.xlsx")
print("All files saved to Downloads Folder")
```

#### Issue:

My current implementation is taking a lot of time to process, especially for larger datasets. I suspect there might be inefficiencies in my code, but I'm not sure where they are.

#### Context:

I'm using Python with libraries such as `tkinter`, `pandas`, `os`, `openpyxl`, `shutil`, and `xlsxwriter` for file operations and data manipulation. I'm running this code on a Windows environment.

#### Expectation:

I expect the code to efficiently split the Excel file by 'Vendor Name' and save each subset as a separate file within the 'Downloads/VendorSplittingApp' folder.

Comment: If you have any questions, please do ask. As I would like your much help possible.

Comment: Your question is hard to get answer. Please read the notice and then ask your question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mre]

Comment: Ok I believe now the code might seem more clear.

Comment: @HP'sPPTs actually, your problem is too complex for a good SO question. Make sure to simplify it to **one core question**. Either this is a file/excel question and state it clearly, or this is a pandas question and thus skip the excel related part and provide minimal example DataFrames as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464). A MRE is just enough code/data to clearly illustrate the expected logic. If really several files are needed, you should provide a way to generate example files (maybe as a small pandas code).

Comment: Should I just skip all parts and just focus on the main problem then?

Comment: Yes, and provide reproducible examples of the data

Comment: Coding questions should have the following three characteristics:

**1. Clarity**: You should clearly explain what you want with examples. Don't think it's enough to provide your code. Nobody read your code to know what you want.

**2. Reproducibility**: When your code is executed, it should produce the same results as you. Of course, even if you provide a file, nobody will download it. So you need to provide a sample example by code. (read notice [mre])

**3. Isolation**: You should isolate the part of the problem that you are having. Nobody will read the entire code you provide.

Comment: Now I have changed the question again, and made it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You look like you are just seeking help *identifying* expensive things. The two most expensive features I see are (1) the nested col/row loops and (2) a file write in the innermost loop.

Unless writing the data file out at every single innermost loop is absolutely necessary (this looks like you're writing per row?) ... move that file write out to the same level as the preceding for(each row).

As a completely different option to help avoid so many writes, you might be able to prepare or re-organise your data using PowerQuery before running your Python code. I don't know what your data looks like, but maybe worth considering.

Next, if there is any chance at all that you can unpack the innermost loop, that may help. This looks like the kind of problemw where you know in advance the number of columns. Unless it's a huge number, unpacking the innermost loop into individual lines of code *may* help. The change may be even more noticeable if the number of columns is small but the number of rows is huge.

Although some of the other operations in your code look like they could be expensive, the ones inside the col/row loops are probably the first to consider.

Finally ... as a completely different approach, you could convert your data to CSV and parse the plain text instead of the Excel objects. That would obviously mean a complete re-code and all, but it is an option.